# Invalid login credentials while Google Play reviews Flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-play-services, google-signin, google-play-console

I have uploaded my Flutter app to the Google Play store and requested a review so the app can be published.
App content is hidden behind google sign-in. I have provided demo account for the reviewers, but app keeps getting rejected because of "Issue: Invalid or incomplete login credentials".

When I run my app locally, with provided demo account details, everything works fine. Both on the emulator and also when I download signed app bundle from the Google Play store. I have tried with multiple different mobile devices and on all of them google sign-in is working with demo account details.

Demo account details (username, password) are provided inside "App content" -> "App access" and are correct ones that I use when testing.

I added SHA-1 and also SHA-256 to the firebase project from both App signing key certificate and Upload key certificate section.

Any ideas, suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After some time I was able to resolve my issue.

Everything is ok from the technical app side. We are using Google login service to authenticate users, but not every user with gmail account can login, but only users that are inside are auth DB.

So we created Google Test account for Google support so they can review with it (test account doesn't have any 2FA, just password). Unfortunately they have some strange policies, they aren't able to login because every time Google account tries to "Verify this is really you..." they don't verify it for some strange reason or whatever, thus resulting in login failure.

What was the fix for this...we recorded a video which demonstrates app functionalities behind the login wall. We recored every in-app screen for at least two seconds. Recored video was hosted and we sent the video link to Google support. They accepted our appeal and the app was accepted and published.